# How do I got about mocking UIApplication.sharedApplication to test shortcutItems?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm trying to write XCTests for my 3D Touch code for quick actions (when you 3D Touch on the icon and launch the app). However, I can't seem to figure out a good way to write a protocol that would allow me to mock `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` so that, when the tests are running and that is called, the test data goes to the mock class instead of the actual `shortcutItems`. Any suggestions?

Originally I was thinking

```
protocol MockShortcutItems {
  var shortcutItems: [UIApplicationShortcutItem] { get set }
}

extension UIApplication: MockShortcutItems {}
```

Comment: Turns out I was close, in the example above I needed to use `var shortcutItems: [UIApplicationShortcutItems]?` instead of what I had. This worked for me to be able to test.